# Query to get a city by a truckload of possible parameters

Tags: sql, zend-framework, search

while testing my search engine, I realised that not only it was pretty awfull, but it didn't work for a lot of combinations the user could input.

I have a search field where the user can input what he wants.
A region, a city name, a zipcode or even a country or any combinations of that in no predetermined order or even predetermined separator.

This is quite difficult to find the cities that could correspond to what the user wants because of the big number of possible combinations the user could enter in that field.

What is even more difficult is that a lot of cities have an article in their name or a composed name, article  or words that the user could or couldn't enter.
For example, since I'm french, I'll use the example of the city called: La Rochelle.

The user could already search for La Rochelle, Rochelle or La-Rochelle just with the city's name. 
With that if he wants to be more precise, he could add the zip-code after, or before, or even the country or both...

I can't find anything about how to optimize the search for a city from some random user input.
Is there some conventional ways to do that ?

The table containing my cities is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
article TEXT,           - contain the article if there's one, or NULL if not
city_name TEXT,         - the city name capitalized
article_upper TEXT,     - the article in upper case
city_name_upper TEXT,   - the city's name in upper-cases
city_slug TEXT,         - the combination of the article + space + city name all in caps
zipcode TEXT,           - the zip-code
country TEXT            - country where the city is located
);
```

What I did was considering that space or ',' where separators and split the string in several words, and then try to match these words with the different fields.

That worked kinda ok except for names with articles or composed of several words, since the article (or other words)  was considered as a different field completely.

What would be the solution to that problem, knowing that forcing the user input or using separate fields are a no go for my client ?

Comment: Can you detect and remove all articles from the input string? In your example, 'La Rochelle' and 'La-Rochelle' would simply become 'Rochelle'

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but that doesn't change the problem for city's name composed of several words such as Aix en Provence or Clermont Ferrand :-/

Comment: I can think of only two real options: Either structure needs to be imposed (either by multiple fields or a defined order of inputs) or you will need to maintain a database of all possible inputs. In the second case, for example, when a string in the input ('La Rochelle') matches a value in your `city` table, you know to use it as a city name parameter.

Comment: Sometimes it is our job as developers to tell the client what does and doesn't work, even if they think differently.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is gonna be slow with TEXT data types. IT doesn't look like you're storing any literary masterpieces in those columns - some regular length-limited varchar columns would probably be fine, much faster too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: Here is where reinventing the wheel is not really appropriate. This is the work of experts and they have generously allowed us to use their work, you may want to start with http://lucene.apache.org/ and http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Comment: I'm using MySQL. 
About Lucene Search, it seems like it's more of an in-document search that something about databses, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect for Full Text Search...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

What I would do is create a summary table with concatenated strings from all the columns in the other table, and put my full-text index on that. And, don't use TEXT data type in your main table, use regular strings - varchar(8000) or whatever...

```
select id, article + ' ' + city_name  + ' ' + zipcode  + ' ' + country
into summary
from cities
```

(You do not need to include the upper case versions, only one version of each word.)

Comment: That depends entirely on what your database engine is. Someone else asked that too. It's critical for us to give any kind of answer. I just posted an example using a popular database. Can't give you much else without knowing what you're using. There are full text searching engines for almost every database.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at the MySQL fulltext search which I didn't know the existence. It seems quite promising, I'm going to look deeper into it and see if it works as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck! The only real solutions for this kind of thing are full-text searching and Google appliances and things like that. I've used the Google appliance and it's very good, if you can afford it.

Comment: Well, your answer seems to respond the closest as what I wanted but I finally made the user choose a more restrictive set of parameters, making it really simple to do. So I didn't have to use your solution, I'll mark it as the answer tho.

Comment: Yeah that's usually a good way to go. Users are often tempted to ask for things they won't really use. I've developed a lot of ignored interfaces over the years. Good luck!